# Cannot extend mock object on run time

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, dart, mockito

when I extend Mock, and try to

```
verify(MockedObject)
```

this error shows:

```
Used on a non-mockito object
package:test_api
```

while:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2ZsU.png)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Your screenshot also seems to say something different then the error message you describe.